# The smallest union closed family containing a collection of subsets

Tags: combinatorics

A family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of a given set $X$ is called union closed when the union of any subcollection of $\mathcal{F}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$.

It is well-known that given a collection of union closed families on $X$, their intersection is again a union closed family. Moreover, the powerset of $X$ is union closed. Therefore, given any family $\mathcal{G}$ I can consider the smallest union closed family containing $\mathcal{G}$.

My question is: how to express the members of the latter union closed family? I think they are the subsets $Y$ of $X$ which can be expressed as the union of collections of subsets of $\mathcal{G}$. Is my intuition correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if we *define*

$$\mathcal{F}^\cup = \{ A \subseteq X\mid \exists \mathcal{F}_A \subseteq \mathcal{F}: A = \bigcup \mathcal{F}_A\}$$

then $\mathcal{F}^\cup$ is closed under all unions and contains $\mathcal{F}$ so $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}^\cup$ if $\mathcal{G}$  is by definition the intersection of **all** union-closed families that contain $\mathcal{F}$.

On the other hand, by definition if $\mathcal{F'}$ is any union-closed family that contains $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathcal{F}^\cup \subseteq \mathcal{F'}$ and hence (as $\mathcal{F'}$ was arbitrary) $\mathcal{F}^\cup \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ and we have equality.

So yes, the smallest such family has a simple description as just $\mathcal{F}^\cup$.